# Round corners of a Path for clipRect not working

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make my corners rounded in a `Path` for `ClipPath`?

```dart
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 10, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 10, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(MyClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

I tried adding this in the middle but it didn't give the desired results

```
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - radius, size.height / 2 - radius, size.width + radius, size.height / 2 + radius);
```

Trying to round this part
[image]

Comment: Can you add a drawing of how you want it to look and what you got when trying with the supplied code

Comment: @PietervanLoon Updated question with image

Answer (score 0):

Draw the black part of this first:
[image: Example]
And then replace the lineTo between the black arrows with the bezier method using the control point

Example how to use the `quadraticBezierTo` method:

```dart
path.moveTo(0, 0);
final controlPoint = Offset(1, 1);
path.quadraticBezierTo(controlPoint.dx, controlPoint.dy, 0, 2);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
```

This draws half an oval.